# How to handle "py4j.Py4JException: Target Object ID does not exist for this gateway"?

Tags: java, python-3.x, py4j

I am running a python service which invokes a jar file to compute something and then do further processing on the data. The whole system works fine except once in a while it starts throwing this error every time I call the java function.

```
    py4j.Py4JException: Target Object ID does not exist for this gateway :o6
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:279)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)
```

When I restarted the python service, it started working normally. It is a rare occurring event so I couldn't try restarting the JVM yet, but that is definitely the next thing I want to try. But till then if anyone has got any suggestions about it?

I am running JVM as a separate process before starting python service.

Comment: We will need more information to help you. Is this always happening at the same place (on the same object/method)? Are you always using the same gatewayserver/java gateway instances? Are there multiple threads accessing the gatewayserver/java gateway? This error could happen if the object was garbage collected on the java side because it was garbage collected on the python side (usually impossible if you keep a hard reference) or if you close the gatewayserver, start a new one, and tries to use a JavaObject you received previously.

Comment: Oh I think that is the issue. I just reproduced it by restarting java server and the error started coming in. Thank you!